# Is There A Way To Call Class Properties Generically?

Tags: c#, generics

Here's some very contrived C# code from LinqPad (I can't share the actual code):

```
void Main()
{
    var d = new DemonstrateIssue();

    Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => {bool result = !d.test1.Contains("y");});
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => {bool result = !d.test2.Contains("y");});
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => {bool result = !d.test3.Contains("y");});
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class DemonstrateIssue
{
    Dictionary<string, string> myTests;
    public string test1 {get;}
    public string test2 {get;}
    public string test3 {get;}

    public DemonstrateIssue()
    {
        myTests = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"test1","yes"},
            {"test2","yep"},
            {"test3","oh yeah!"}
        };

        test1 = myTests["test1"];
        test2 = myTests["test2"];
        test3 = myTests["test3"];
    }
}
```

I'm doing tests with NUnit to check that each property conforms to the same behavior. The thing is, as you can see, it's basically the same test each time except for the class field I'm calling it on.  When I see code of that sort I always want to replace it with generic code but I can't figure out how to get each property in a generic fashion.  It seems like I need to use reflection but I was hoping there might be some generic way to code this.

I mean I was thinking of something like this

```
public void TestField<T>()
{
   Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => {bool result = id.T.contains("y");}); 
}
```

Where T would be the string field but I can't figure out how to do this if it's even possible. Any suggestions or thoughts on how I might DRY up this code would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda expression to store the properties in a list. Then iterate over the list and test each element.

```
void Main()
{
    var d = new DemonstrateIssue();
    var properties = new List<Func<DemonstrateIssue,string>>
    {
        x => x.test1,
        x => x.test2,
        x => x.test3
    };

    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => bool result = !p(d).Contains("y");});
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little new to best practices in unit testing. Any particular reason to use a List of Func's instead of just a list of strings in this case?

Comment: The code I have provided is bound at compile time. If you were to use a list of strings, they would not be checked until runtime.